# jQuery equal.Heights plugin - "$.browser.msie is null or not an object"?

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to js in general, but from the tutorials I've read it seems like this should work.  I'm just trying to use this plugin to make 3 boxes equal height... the boxes have border-radius and some other styling applied if that matters.

Script code:

```
$.fn.equalHeights = function(px) {
$(this).each(function(){
var currentTallest = 0;
$(this).children().each(function(i){
if ($(this).height() > currentTallest) { currentTallest = $(this).height(); }
});
    if (!px && Number.prototype.pxToEm) currentTallest = currentTallest.pxToEm(); //use ems unless px is specified
// for ie6, set height since min-height isn't supported
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) { $(this).children().css({'height': currentTallest}); }
$(this).children().css({'min-height': currentTallest});
});
return this;
};

// just in case you need it...
$.fn.equalWidths = function(px) {
$(this).each(function(){
var currentWidest = 0;
$(this).children().each(function(i){
if($(this).width() > currentWidest) { currentWidest = $(this).width(); }
});
if(!px && Number.prototype.pxToEm) currentWidest = currentWidest.pxToEm(); //use ems unless px is specified
// for ie6, set width since min-width isn't supported
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) { $(this).children().css({'width': currentWidest}); }
$(this).children().css({'min-width': currentWidest});
});
return this;
};
```

Page code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


<script src = "js/jQuery.equalHeights.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(function(){ $('#equalize').equalHeights(); });
    });
</script>
```

And I've applied the id of "equalize" to my div that contains the three boxes I want equal height.  It doesn't seem to have an effect, and IE throws the script error "$.browser.msie is null or not an object".

I'm running this locally on a php page using xampp, if that's applicable.

I'm very sure this is just some stupid newb mistake on my part, I seriously spent like 2 hours trying to chase it down and I give up.  If anyone can chime in, I'd REALLY appreciate it!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: `$.browser()` is removed in the `Jquery 1.9` version.http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed.  So, you need to use some other Javascript lib or use older version of Jquery.

Comment: Srinivas, thank you.  I was not aware of the differences introduced in the 1.9 version.  I've marked the answer below as correct since using the jQuery Migrate plugin solved the problem, but I appreciate your explanation too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need [jQuery Migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/) for old code.